# Boogie Woogie - Hands synchronization

Tags: piano

I'm very much a beginner piano player and I started learning boogie woogie a few months ago. I started learning the base first (LH) and then some patterns with my RH. Now what I find difficult is how to get both hand in sync knowing that my LH is just repeating a pattern that I'm not really thinking which note I'm hitting, it becomes automatic.

Is there any way to solve that, especially when playing from sheet music where the notes need to be synchronized between both hands?

Comment: FWIW, for synchronization I've noticed that it's better to think of performing _one single instantaneous action_ that happens to produce a sound that can be perceived as multiple component pitches. And don't think of performing two sounds/notes as separate independent actions that should happen at the same time. Like if you push something with two hands, it's just one single thing you're pushing, even though you use both hands to do it. Concentrate on the _sound_. Whenever the sheet music has notes starting at the same time position, it means one sound, like a single chord. Find those points.

Comment: Concentrate on the sound.. Nice advice (y)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to practice independence of the hands is this:

Start playing your pattern with the left hand (slowly!). With the right hand, play one fixed note on the first beat of every bar. This should be simple.

Now play quarter notes with the right hand - still stay on one note though. Practice until it is fluent. Speed it up a little until you feel comfortable with the new tempo.

Repeat and continue that exercise with various simple and later more complex rhythms with the right hand. E.g. play eighth notes, then play two eighths, a quarter break, two eighths, a quarter break. Later add playing only off-beats or even a Latin rhythm.

The key is:

- play it slowly with a simple rhythm until you feel comfortable (i.e. it runs automatically).
- Speed it up a little. Again practice until you’re comfortable.

It will take you a few weeks of daily training to be able to comfortably play independent rhythms with your right hand. But you will most likely feel the first hint of “independence” on day one :)

Comment: Looks like I need to re learn that piece with slowing down the LH.

Answer (score 0):

To synchronize hands, it always helped me sitting down with my hands on a table and the music sheet in front. Then I was just hitting the table with the LH/RH as you would play on the piano. This way you get synchronization without having to worry about playing the correct note.